# Unable to find component for ID in view

Tags: jsf, primefaces

In a JSF, Primefaces 6 project, I get the following warning:

```
Unable to find component for ID dateFrom_input in view
```

Here is the view:

```
<h:outputLabel for="dateFrom_input" />
<p:autoComplete id="dateFrom" ...></p:autoComplete>
```

p:autoComplete is replaced by:

```
<span id="searchForm:dateFrom">
    <input id="searchForm:dateFrom_input" name="searchForm:dateFrom_input" type="text" autocomplete="off">
    ...
</span>
```

Basically, I have to set the label for component dateFrom_input to get the feature working (I mean clicking on label to jump in the field...). It works but the warning appear.

It looks I cannot make reference to something in a widget...

How two shut this warning up?

**UPDATE**

In a DOM point of view, what I do is correct (label for parameter set with the input ID). But in a JSF point of view, p:autocomplete field is not yet "compiled" as HTML and it cannot reach the input (which effectively take ID dateFrom_input once compiled)

Comment: JSF component ID != HTML element ID

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use the following:

```
<p:outputLabel for="dateFrom" value="Click here! "/>
<p:autoComplete id="dateFrom" ...></p:autoComplete>
```

Comment: Not working. To make it working, you must set the <input> ID in the for parameter, not the <p:autocomplete> one. And when you do what I said, a warning appears because the input is not found...

Comment: No, you must not. You must use p:outputLabel and not h:outputLabel, exactly as I have written above